# How to add new value to existing table column value

Tags: mysql

I know this can update a table column to a new value from the previous value `UPDATE table SET column=column+2` but this only happen to an integer value, I want to update a text value like this

```
// if the table column value is = "james,john,peter"
$new = ",andrew";

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET column=column+'".$new."');
```

so the new table column value will now be `james,john,peter,andrew`. I have searched even stackoverflow but all answers I got is for integer value. Please anyone with an idea?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. Don't store multiple values in a single column

Comment: @juergend Although your right, one should use a second table for multiple values, the question is only how to concatenate a string value

Comment: @juergend... its not my original code. not even the query, query will be extented  like this `WHERE id = '".$id."'`, I just want to know how its done, because if I stored the values in a row for each the I will be having like 500 rows and more just for an id and I have multiple ids up to 200, so finally I may end up having up to 100,000 rows in a table which I don't think it's health

Comment: Having millions of rows is no problem. Having multiple values in a column is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `concat()` function:

```
UPDATE table set column=concat(column, ',andrew');
```